# MobilePush Reset SubscriberKey

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, journeybuilder, mobilepush

We have the iOS MobilePush SDK setup in our app.  We can send broadcast mobile push messages and geofenced messages.

In our app, the guest can sign in and when they do, we are calling setSubscriberKey to associate the signed in user with their ET Email account.

```
\\ Assigning subscriber key.
[[ETPush pushManager] setSubscriberKey: [user userId]];
```

So far so good.

Now the question is this:

*On sign out, what is the appropriate way to unassociate the device from the ET Email account?*

I tried to set the subscriber key to `nil` with no effect.

```
\\ Attempting to remove subscriber key, does not work.
[[ETPush pushManager] setSubscriberKey:nil];
```

I can just set the value of the subscriber key to a random GUID, but I am not clear is that is a great idea or not.

Comment: This is a great question... Ever get an answer?

Comment: The resolution we arrived at was to generate a new GUID / UUID in app and set it to that value, rather then nil.

Answer (score 1):

This would be an appropriate approach, as "nil" would be an invalid value (documented in ETPush.h as "Cannot be nil or blank."). You'd then be able to restrict/retard the matching of your business logic against an email address for segmentation.